# postgresql query for hour minutes and seconds

Tags: postgresql

Hi I am having a Postgresql query like below to calculate DateTime difference for {1} and {2} in minutes.

```
CAST(ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH from (({2}::timestamp) - ({1}::timestamp)))/60) AS INT)
```

I want to calculate the difference in hours, minutes and seconds displayed like:

> 3 hrs 31 minutes 42 secs

What manipulation do I need for displaying like above?

Comment: Are time differences of >= 24 hours possible? Also, please provide the exact data types of source columns and your version of Postgres. The question is ambiguous without it.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT to_char((col1 - col0), 'HH24 hrs MI "minutes" SS "seconds"') FROM T1;
```

Here is a sqlfiddle : [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dac33/3)

The to_char function takes an interval (an interval is the time span between two timestamps, and subtracting timestamps gives you an interval). It then takes a formatting, and you can apply pretty much what you want.

[Formatting functions in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Subtracting *dates* gives you an `ìnteger` (the number of days in between). Subtracting *timestamps* produces an `interval`, which is never called "date interval".

Answer (score 2):

Try use this sql:

SELECT to_char(column2 - column1, 'DD" days "HH24" hours "MI" minutes "SS" seconds"');

Answer (score 1):

The subtraction of two `timestamp` or `timestamptz` values produces an `interval`. (While subtracting two `date` values produces an `integer`!)
[Details about date/time types in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

The default text representation of an `interval` may be sufficient:

```
SELECT timestamp '2017-1-6 12:34:56' - timestamp '2017-1-1 0:0';
```

Result is an `interval`, displayed as:

```
5 days 12:34:56
```

If you need the format in the question, precisely, you need to specify how to deal with intervals >= 24 hours. Add *'days'*? Or just increase hours accordingly?

[@Nobody provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412884/939860) how to use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE). But add days one way or the other:

```
SELECT to_char(ts_col2 - ts_col1, 'DD" days "HH24" hours "MI" minutes "SS" seconds"');
```

Result:

```
05 days 12 hours 34 minutes 56 seconds
```

*'days'* covers the rest. There are no greater time units in the result by default.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(year FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) - yourFieldTime)||' year '||
  EXTRACT(month FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) - yourFieldTime)||' month '||
  EXTRACT(day FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) - yourFieldTime)||' day '||
  EXTRACT(hour FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) - yourFieldTime)||' hour '||
  EXTRACT(minute FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) - yourFieldTime)||' minute '||
  EXTRACT(second FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) - yourFieldTime)||' second '
AS full_time_as_you_wish FROM your_table;
```

Result

> **full_time_as_you_wish**
>
> ---------------------------------
>
> 0 year 0 month 0 day 0 hour 0 minute 0 second